# Android OpenGL software / hardware renderer devices list

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm creating OpenGL application based on `AndEngine` and I'm really surprised by the differences between fps on various devices. So, the question is that: which devices use the OpenGL software renderer, which have their own GPU (but without proper drivers), and which have GPU and use it well?

Also, is there any possibility for reducing Android Market application visibility only for devices which DO have hardware renderer (manifest `<uses-feature>` maybe?)?

Comment: I'm dying for a great answer to this question. The HTC Thunderbolt is giving me grief, and I have a hunch that it is using software for some OpenGL calls which is slowing my game down quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an HTC Evo? That one is a weird case, because the fps is being artificially limited.

Have you downloaded the AndEngine Examples app from the Market? That app lets you run some benchmarks on your device, and then submit the results to the AndEngine developer.

His app is not the only one that's doing it. There are at least two or three other benchmark apps or demo apps that collect this kind of data, and hopefully publish the results somewhere. I'll try to track them down when I have a minute.

And yes, do look for a uses-feature tag that would do the trick. The uses-feature tag is the only way to filter apps in the market.

Comment: Yes, I own HTC Evo, but got no problem with fps. I've downloaded AndEngine examples and benchmarked the devices I have, and I have implemented the benchmark in my app too. But I've got problem with devices with software OGL renderer, and I cannot find any method to prevent them from accessing my app through AM.